# What kind of neural network model to build to identify that the algo is n*n?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working with @tensorflow/tfjs-node to play with neural networks. I'm a beginner and don't yet fully grasp how they work, nor do I understand the mathematics behind it. But I like to play with them for fun.

So, what I'm playing with right now is I create a sequence: [1, 2, ..., n], and a function, for example `n => n + 4` or `n => n * 2`, and I map it to the labels. Then my goal is to predict n+1, n+2, etc with the neural network without knowing the function.

Played with different kind of dense layers and different activations and optimizers, and usually after 1000 epochs on, for n = 1000, I get a very low loss. Which is perfect!

But here comes to bomb. I can't seem to get a low loss for n => n * n.

The code I'm playing with is here: https://pastebin.com/KSjAraF0

Comment: Actually, I was unable to deduce this from the code, but which activation function are you using?

Comment: I don't use any activation function. https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.dense if unspecified no activation function is applied.

Comment: This means that the model has a linear activation function. A linear model cannot approximate a non-linear function of n^2. You need to apply a sigmoid non-linearity in your dense layer.

Comment: To be more specific, a neural network with no activation function, no matter how wide and deep, is equivalent to a linear model (that is, each output will be a linear combination of the inputs), which, as Shubham pointed out, won't be able to learn a non-linear function. In theory, any non-linear activation function should allow a "large-enough" network to learn any function. Sigmoid is the "classic" choice, but there are a bunch of other typical ones (tanh, relu, ...). For the output layer, since it is a regression problem, you may use linear activation (no activation function).

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Even with sigmoid I still can't make it learn. https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-gauss-mqpi8

Answer (score 0):

I found the following snippet. That helped me achieve function detection.

https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_105_tf_polynomial_regression/P5/sketch.js

However, it's not really the same, because here you know that some things get multiplied. But I believe that's how I need to think about AI, learn to model the problem, that's where 99% of effort is.